# Refreshing token obtained through "sign in with twitter"

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-mobile-services

I am using Twitter for Authentication, and Azure Web API (Auth in Azure mobile Apps is same) is issuing a token to my app with a lifetime of a month.

[This Blog](http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/) by a Microsoft employee states that you can refresh the token by making a request to

```
myAzureApiApp/.auth/refresh
```

But when I issue a GET request to this endpoint with a header

```
X-ZUMO-AUTH: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1...
```

I get Bad Request. However when I send an invalid token I get Unauthorised.

I also noticed that this blog does not mention refresh tokens for twitter and Facebook, yet they are mentioned for Google, Microsoft and Azure AD.

Can I refresh my Azure Api / Mobile App token, issued with Twitter sign in?

Answer (score 0):

Short version is that the Identity Provider must support refresh tokens.  Twitter, based on [their documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/introduction), does not support refresh tokens.

Comment: If I understand things right, Twitter token do not expire, but the token provided by Azure App services does. So we are in the strange situation that if you use twitter, you will have to re-enter your username every month. 

I think App service should either issue a token with lifetime to match Twitter's, or refresh the App Service's token as long as the Twitter's one is still valid.

We intend to go with the client flow: get the token from twitter ourselves, and then provide it to Azure App service to get new Access token when the current ones expire.